# ModuleNotFoundError al intentar importar las funciones de un archivo en otro

Tags: python, python-import

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este fichero en Python, y necesito importar las funciones de *user_functions.py* a mi archivo de *consumer.py*. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Estoy haciendo esto:

```py
from functions.user_functions import *
```

pero cuando hago `python consumer.py` me da este error (ya intente yendo al path principal  hacer `python consumers/consumer.py` y lo mismo):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joaqu\Desktop\Ejercicio Practico\Consumers\consumer.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functions.user_functions import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las funciones sí las importa, es decir, puedo llamarlas y si les doy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clic izq, voy hacia el archivo *user_functions.py*, pero al momento de correrlo con `python` me tira ese error.

Comment: Recomiendo cambiar el titulo por: Error de importación en Python (Describe mas el problema de tu código que error de principiante).

Comment: Las rutas son relativas al script en cuestión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sucede porque Python no ejecuta desde la carpeta de tu proyecto, sino desde donde se encuentra el archivo Python(`./consumers/consumer.py`). Para solucionarlo puedes poner la carpeta de tu proyecto en el PATH de Python:

```Python
import sys;
sys.path.append("../");
from functions.user_functions import *;
```

##### Enlace externo

- [Ganchos de importación](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/reference/import.html#import-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

comando para facilitar esta tarea para el PYTHONPATH

***#Windows (PowerShell):***

## Agregar al PYTHONPATH

$env:PYTHONPATH += ";C:\ruta\de\proyecto"

## Verificar PYTHONPATH

$env:PYTHONPATH

## Eliminar del PYTHONPATH

$env:PYTHONPATH = $env:PYTHONPATH -replace ";C:\ruta\de\proyecto", ""

## Verificar PYTHONPATH después de eliminar

$env:PYTHONPATH

#***Linux y macOS (Bash)*:**

## Agregar al PYTHONPATH

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"/ruta/de/proyecto"

## Verificar PYTHONPATH

echo $PYTHONPATH

## Eliminar del PYTHONPATH

export PYTHONPATH=$(echo $PYTHONPATH | sed -e 's|:/ruta/de/proyecto||')

## Verificar PYTHONPATH después de eliminar

echo $PYTHONPATH